# How to Identify Client uniqueness?

Tags: api, rest, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api, api-design

**TL;DR;** Is there any way to bind a (Bearer?) token to a unique client, and represent that in the HTTP REQ Headers?

In the scenario that a user has an account to a service. The same user should be able to consume the services using different client applications (different Browsers, native mobile APPs). The best approach would be, for each distinct environment, a login process should be followed (OAuth2?) were each app acquires a token (bearer token). Then each client is able to consume the services, and by identifying them selves with the token, the services provider is able to scope their use.

This works fine most of the times, although what happens when the service provider wants to isolate the use of each token to the specific client?

For sure in a security incident, the provider can just drop the collection/table that holds the tokens, but wouldn't be better for the client to pass an md5 of their unique identifier (maybe a `md5(concat(app.version, environment.name, username))`) along with their auth token?

P.S.: I think passing such value as a property inside the body's payload is invalid. Since such authentication step should happen while the server reads the HTTP headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clients are uniquely identified by the client identifier (`client_id`). The `client_id` may come back in the result of the Bearer token access validation and the Resource Server may keep a blacklist, although it is more likely that the Authorization Server would blacklist it.

If you're looking to improve security by ensuring that the client presenting the token is the actual client that the token was issued to, that is being addressed in extensions of OAuth 2.0, see: http://www.thread-safe.com/2014/04/oauth-proof-of-possession-drafts.html

So wrt. to client uniqueness: it is ensured through the `client_id`. Wrt. security: any proposal that does not include a secret to bind the token to the client does not improve things security wise.

Comment: I see your point, no doubt `client_id` is part of the process. Yes Client uniqueness can be spoofed. I Guess I could work around that by doing `md5(concat(app.version, env.name, username, verifier(salt, username, secret)))` where the salt would be part of the payload, of client Auth. Thanks for the references!